# Changing prop value with onError when MUI DateTimePicker error=true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change 'myError' to true when MUI DateTimePicker throws onError but it doesn't work. The whole code itself is correct because when I change

```
() => {setValue({
              ...value,
              myError: true
```

to alert('something') it works. I want to use this *myError* variable to manage submit button - disable it when an error occurs and enable it when it's not.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({
    myError: false,
      })

<DateTimePicker
            
            onError = {() => {setValue({
              ...value,
              myError: true
            }) }}
            />
```

Any ideas what should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`onError`](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-time-picker/#props) is a callback with the signature:

> Signature:
>
> ```
> function(reason: TError, value: TInputValue) => void
> ```
>
> **reason**: The reason why the current value is not valid.
>
> **value**: The invalid value.

so what you should do there is to set `myError` if there is a `reason`, like this:

```
onError={(reason) => setValue({ myError: Boolean(reason) })}
```

if you want to go further and show the error `reason`, you can see this [guide](https://next.material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/forms) on how to.

you can see an example below

[image: Edit aged-haze-q33ffw]

Comment: It worked when I changed to

`const [myError, setMyError] = useState(false);
onError = {() => {
            setMyError(true) }}`

Comment: that works too but `myError` will still have `true` if there is no value in `DateTimePicker`

Comment: Yup, I add `disabled = {(myError == true) && !(date==null)? true : false} ` to the button and works just fine

Comment: and  `onAccept= {() => {  setMyError(false) }}` to the DateTimePicker